# K8 Dual stack one master and multiple worker nodes - centos7

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, gcp

I have k8 dual stack one master and multiple worker node(oci-centos7). how I can failover if my master nodes goes down or whether it will impact running pods on worker nodes?